# JavaScript: events keypress

Tags: javascript

I'm confused on how this set of code is suppose to select the button by pressing the "g" on the keyboard:

[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: Please add your code snippet to the post, and define "select the button".

Comment: The example is only adding (or removing if already added) the `btn-like` class. I'm guessing the class has styling properties that make it appear selected, as opposed to appearing unselected.

Comment: What are you specifically confused about? The event listener, the callback, jQuery selectors? It looks like you are following a tutorial, which should explain everything that's going on but if you are confused by a specific part of the code, that is something that can be explained.

Comment: Write the code on this tool: https://jsfiddle.net/ for tests. And improve your question adding the code to it otherwise you will start getting down votes.

Comment: Damon i'm confused about why the code i placed in didn't work. I am following the tutorial but i think it was combining 2 lessons. how to select the button and activating the dropdown menu when pressing a letter on the keyboard. The code i placed in is wrong and i'm not sure why.

Comment: check this little part of the instructions: "Use `$('.btn')` to select the Like button".

Comment: Copy the code from that page, [edit] your question, and paste the code into the question itself. This question does not not have the code (or text) necessary to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of keypress in jquery

```
$(selector).keypress(function)
```

You may follow http://www.k68.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Key_Codes.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).keypress(function(event){
                    if(event.which == 103) {
                           //Your Code
                        }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As i can read your provided code image will work.
it has one problem which trap all event of this element which is not right based on description of provided example.
their should be `$('.btn').toggleClass("btn-like")`